# Typescript issue this.ref.push() does not work

Tags: ionic4

I don’t know what seems to be the problem here:

```js
export class ProfilePage implements OnInit {
  data: Observable<any[]>;
  ref: AngularFireList<any>;
```

and

```js
constructor(private afs: AngularFirestore, private user: UserService, public NavCtrl: NavController, private db: AngularFireDatabase, private toastCtrl: ToastController, public toastcontroller: ToastController) {
   }
async addTransaction() {
  this.ref.push(this.transaction).then(() => {
    this.transaction = {
      value: 0,
      expense: false,
      month: 0
    };
  });
}
```

this is what the console shows:

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError:
>   Cannot read property 'push' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read
>   property 'push' of undefined

Comment: Can you show your constructor content?

Comment: Here you go, posted the constructor

Comment: where did you initialize `this.ref`? Is it possible you are accessing `addTransaction` method before `this.ref` has a value?

Comment: Yes, this.ref does not have a value initially. What do I do?

Comment: initialize this.ref in the constructor.